# How to check the asyncapi/studio version when on https://studio.asyncapi.com/

Tags: asyncapi

If I am using editor on https://studio.asyncapi.com, is there a way to check the async api studio version using the web console? Thanks

I tried looking for any version files in the Sources tab and Debugger, but couldn't find any. I also tried async.version, but din't work as well